# Bind an isolated scope property dynamically to an array

Tags: angularjs

I create inside the controller the arrays:

```
$scope.options0=[];
$scope.options1=[];
...
$scope.options9=[];
```

I use a directive:

```
myapp.directive('selectedItems',  function() {
    return {   
      scope: {
        temp: '='
      },
      link:function(scope,element){...}
    }
})
```

and inside the view:

```
<div selected-items temp="options+$index"></div>
```

where $index comes from a previous ng-repeat and gets values between 0 and 9. ***I want to bind temp with options0 or options1 or ...***, according to the $index value. I have tried all combinations. Nothing works. Any idea?

Comment: You want two way binding between directive(temp) and the controller values(options0 or options1 or ...)?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: Then don't apply scope in directive. Directly use the values of scope in directive controller. If you use scope, isolated scope created and two-way data binding wont happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make `options` a single object instead of a whole bunch of individual scope properties

```
$scope.options ={
   '0': []
   '1': [],
   '2': []
}
```

Then it is easy to reference in view (or function) using `[]` notation

```
<div selected-items temp="options[$index]"></div>
```

Comment: However, this is not exactly what I want. In the controller I have to have the following code: `for (var i=0; i<self.Data.length;i++) {
             $scope['options'+i]=[];
         }` . Granted that, how may I **bind temp**?

Comment: just change to `$scope.options[i]=[];` and declare `$scope.options={}` before run the loop

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$scope.options[0]=[];
$scope.options[1]=[];
...
$scope.options[9]=[];
```

In directive:

```
myapp.directive('selectedItems',  function() {
    return {   

      link:function($scope){
          console.log($scope.options[$scope.$index])
      }
   }
})
```

This might work for you.

Comment: you have to define `$scope.options` first

Comment: Ok fine. Thankyou.